# Using a curve's calc_length() method in a driver expression?

Tags: bezier-curves, drivers

Recently I've dipped my toes into Blender's drivers & expression system.
I'm trying to scale a road to exactly fit the length of the curve it's following.
[image: Road doesn't fit to curve length]

I came across this post of two years ago: https://developer.blender.org/D1810
Which apparently enables you to get the exact length of any curve, simply by using the calc_length() method.

However, apparently this doesn't work? The RNA gives a red error color & "var" defaults to 0.
[image: RNA gives an error]

Any of you guys know what I'm doing wrong? I can't help but think I'm overlooking some very obvious thing.

Thank you!

Comment: The call to `calc_length()` needs to be done inside the `Scripted Expression`. Note: it turns out this patch wasn't committed, will look into this today.

Comment: I went digging through Blender source code and I found that internally there is already a variable which defines a curve's length: "totdist". https://i.imgur.com/ejKLh56.png The array modifier uses this in its "Fit Length" mode. Might be possible to expose that variable somehow?

Comment: Committed https://developer.blender.org/rB537bf6af0cd80ac0ef0f55f7ab68540a09db8f37